# Loading images from URL with special characters isn't working

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I'm working on an app that looks up an item through a web service. In the resulting information there are image URLs which I then use to display images.

Everything works perfectly, except when there are special characters in the URL for images.

Here's the basic code I'm using:

```
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://FULLURL/image-é.jpg"]];

 cell.cellView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
```

The data variable is always nil when the URL contains special characters, but works when there aren't any.

I tried a couple methods of encoding the string with NSUTF8StringEncoding, and NSASCIIStringEncoding with no luck. The data variable is always nil.

Comment: Share the actual URL so I can try it on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used en.wikipedia.org/wiki/É as my URL to test this out. Try this code:

```
NSString *string = [@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/É" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Great that worked. I must not have gotten the encoding correctly when I tried it. Thanks for the help!